# Incrementally Adding 1 Until Sum is Reached

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a problem I can't seem to work out.

I have a range that when the sum of column C is less than 50, I would like to incrementally add 1 to each row in column C starting from the top until the total is 50 (and looping back to the top if necessary). There are 10 rows and they are fixed. The values in row "abc1" and "abc2" will always be 2 and will not change.

In the example in the image below, the total of the 10 entries is 38. Starting at "A" I would like to add 1, working it's way down until the ten rows sum to 50.

I appreciate the assistance.

[correct values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fayyq.jpg)

[incorrect values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SHgT.jpg)

[incorrect values #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyYFa.jpg)

I do not know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Either Solver or vba should be able to do this. Several questions on here show possible methods.

Comment: What have you tried? Are the number of rows fixed? Is it an actual table or a range. If a table, what's the name?

Comment: I also see you tagged Excel 2010. Is that accurate? Also is the number of rows fixed (will it always be 8)?

Comment: This is a different question. Are you sure it's fixed, since your original question showed 8 rows and a goal of 70. Where does the range start/end, should that be dynamical?

Comment: So nothing to do with the original problem of column B and a total of 780 then.

Comment: So how do you expect the output to appear and where?

Comment: Your picture shows 12 values that sum up to 38, not 10 values. Also please don't change the entire question. I see Solar Mike pointing at a different question than me and both don't resemble the current. Also how can you say it's fixed if you changed it 3 times? Do you really seek for help, or are you just messing?

Answer (score 0):

Original answer for when the question showed 8 rows in column B and a goal of 70:

`=B1:B8+INT((70-B9)/8)+(ROW(B1:B8)<=MOD(70-B9,8))`

Where `B9` is the sum of `B1:B8` and `8` is the number of rows.

If it needs to be dynamical or it doesn't start at row 1, you need to properly update the question.

Not sure if this requires being entered with `ctrl+shift+enter` in older Excel.

`=LET(goal,50,all,TOCOL(M:M/ISNUMBER(M:M),3),total,TAKE(all,-1),numbers,DROP(all,-1),r,ROWS(numbers),gap,goal-total,c,numbers+INT(gap/r)+(SEQUENCE(r)<=MOD(gap,r)),c)`

For current question (12 rows, goal 50)

Skipping last 2 rows in adding 1:

```
=LET(goal,50,
     all,FILTER(M:M,ISNUMBER(M:M)),
     total,SUM(DROP(all,-1)),
     numbers,DROP(all,-1),
     r,ROWS(DROP(numbers,-2)),
     gap,goal-total,
IFNA(numbers+INT(gap/r)+(SEQUENCE(r)<=MOD(gap,r)),numbers))
```

Comment: Can you explain: *"It seems to go haywire"* what happens, what's wrong compared to what you expect?

Comment: I see what you mean, values disappear and calculation is off if you change values until you recalculate the function. I'll have a look later today.

Comment: Instead of TOCOL using FILTER fixes it. Not sure why TOCOL behaves that way.

Comment: It works correct with my Excel with your example values also when changing. I'm using the Office 365 for Mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

So something like:

[image]

Using the Solver, sumproduct() and a sum().