# Tranpose irregular rows into columns and shift one row down

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an Excel file with this data format.

[image]

Now I want to transform those data into column, like this.

[image]

How should I do that with Excel Formula or VBA scripts?

I have tried using Transpose paste but it overwrites the rows underneath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Excel` Formulas it can be accomplished like as below:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A6</kbd>

```
=HSTACK(TOCOL(IFS(B2:E4<>"",A2:A4),3),TOCOL(B2:E4,1))
```

---

Also I had prefer using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>. To achieve this using the said procedure, follow this simple steps using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd> window `UI`:

[image]

---

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table_1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_1"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"SKU"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Value", "Images"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

[image]

---

Comment: I like the formula solution, but my advice is to use argument `2` instead of `3` for Tocol, in case the values are results of a formula. See more about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77563158/tocol-function-does-not-give-expected-results

Answer (score 1):

- Load source table into an array
- Transform data and write to sheet

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range
    Dim arrRes, iR As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Set rngData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData) * UBound(arrData, 2), 1)
    iR = 1
    arrRes(iR, 0) = "SKU"
    arrRes(iR, 1) = "Image"
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        For j = LBound(arrData, 2) + 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)
            If Len(arrData(i, j)) = 0 Then Exit For
            iR = iR + 1
            arrRes(iR, 0) = arrData(i, 1)
            arrRes(iR, 1) = arrData(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    Sheets.Add
    Range("A1").Resize(iR, 2).Value = arrRes
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=LET(
    x, A1:E4,
    r, TAKE(DROP(x, 1), , 1),
    c, DROP(x, 1, 1),
    HSTACK(TOCOL(IFS(c > 0, r), 2), TOCOL(c, 1))
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Transpose irregular rows to columns

Here is a simple way of achieving what the OP wants.

```
Sub sbTransposeRowCol()

 Dim iRows, iColumns, iRow, iColumn, iResultRow As Long
 Dim sText, sSKU As String

' first select the Range to be transposed
 Dim rSelectedRange As Range
 Set rSelectedRange = Application.Selection
 iColumns = rSelectedRange.Columns.Count
 iRows = rSelectedRange.Rows.Count
 
' add the headings as required
 iResultRow = iRows + 2
 Cells(iResultRow, 1) = "SKU"
 Cells(iResultRow, 2) = "Images"
 iResultRow = iResultRow + 1

' rewrite the selected range missing out blank cells
 For iRow = 2 To iRows
  For iColumn = 1 To iColumns
   ' Use the .Text in the Cell not .Value to deal with formula results
   If iColumn = 1 Then sSKU = Cells(iRow, iColumn).Text
   If iColumn <> 1 Then sText = Cells(iRow, iColumn).Text
   If sText = "" Then
    ' skip it
   Else
    Cells(iResultRow, 1) = sSKU
    Cells(iResultRow, 2) = sText
    iResultRow = iResultRow + 1
    sText = ""
   End If
  Next iColumn
 Next iRow
End Sub
```

Here is the OP's example data

| SKU | Image 1 | Image 2 | Image 3 | Image 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SKU-ABC | img1url | img2url | img3url | img4url |
| SKU-DEF | img1url | img2url |  |  |
| SKU-XYZ | img1url | img2url | img3url |  |

This seems like it could be useful in a general sense so here is the function that implements it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub sbUsage()
 Call fnTransposeRowColIreg
End Sub

Function fnTransposeRowColIreg()
 ' Transpose Irregular Rows to Columns
 Dim iRows, iColumns, iRow, iColumn, iResultRow As Long
 Dim sText1, sText2 As String
 Dim rIrregularRange As Range
 Set rIrregularRange = Application.Selection
 iColumns = rIrregularRange.Columns.Count
 iRows = rIrregularRange.Rows.Count
 iResultRow = iRows + 2

 For iRow = 1 To iRows
  For iColumn = 1 To iColumns
   ' Use the .Text in the Cell not .Value to deal with formula results
   If iColumn = 1 Then sText1 = Cells(iRow, iColumn).Text
   If iColumn <> 1 Then sText2 = Cells(iRow, iColumn).Text
   If sText2 = "" Then
    ' skip it
   Else
    Cells(iResultRow, 1) = sText1
    Cells(iResultRow, 2) = sText2
    iResultRow = iResultRow + 1
    sText2 = ""
   End If
  Next iColumn
 Next iRow
End Function
```